# Way to remove the Override Title form option in Panel component config?

Tags: 7, panels

I am making a Panel Component, in D7, and do not want to show the title. I can just not render out the title on the page - that's fine - but I'd also like to remove the form fields that allow you to enter in the title.

[image]

Would anyone know how to do this? I cannot find any info out there.

Comment: Have you tried using hook_form_alter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function responsible for the overriding title:

```
/**
 * Add the default FAPI elements to the content type configuration form.
 */
function ctools_content_configure_form_defaults($form, &$form_state) {
  $plugin = $form_state['plugin'];
  $subtype = $form_state['subtype'];
  $contexts = isset($form_state['contexts']) ? $form_state['contexts'] : NULL;
  $conf = $form_state['conf'];

  $add_submit = FALSE;
  if (!empty($subtype['required context']) && is_array($contexts)) {
    $form['context'] = ctools_context_selector($contexts, $subtype['required context'], isset($conf['context']) ? $conf['context'] : array());
    $add_submit = TRUE;
  }

  ctools_include('dependent');

  // Unless we're not allowed to override the title on this content type, add this
  // gadget to all panes.
  if (empty($plugin['no title override']) && empty($subtype['no title override'])) {
    $form['aligner_start'] = array(
      '#markup' => '<div class="option-text-aligner clearfix">',
    );
    $form['override_title'] = array(
      '#type' => 'checkbox',
      '#default_value' => isset($conf['override_title']) ? $conf['override_title'] : '',
      '#title' => t('Override title'),
      '#id' => 'override-title-checkbox',
    );
    $form['override_title_text'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#default_value' => isset($conf['override_title_text']) ? $conf['override_title_text'] : '',
      '#size' => 35,
      '#id' => 'override-title-textfield',
      '#dependency' => array('override-title-checkbox' => array(1)),
      '#dependency_type' => 'hidden',
    );
    $form['override_title_heading'] = array(
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#default_value' => isset($conf['override_title_heading']) ? $conf['override_title_heading'] : 'h2',
      '#options' => array(
        'h1' => t('h1'),
        'h2' => t('h2'),
        'h3' => t('h3'),
        'h4' => t('h4'),
        'h5' => t('h5'),
        'h6' => t('h6'),
        'div' => t('div'),
        'span' => t('span'),
      ),
      '#id' => 'override-title-heading',
      '#dependency' => array('override-title-checkbox' => array(1)),
      '#dependency_type' => 'hidden',
    );

    $form['aligner_stop'] = array(
      '#markup' => '</div>',
    );
    if (is_array($contexts)) {
      $form['override_title_markup'] = array(
        '#prefix' => '<div class="description">',
        '#suffix' => '</div>',
        '#markup' => t('You may use %keywords from contexts, as well as %title to contain the original title.'),
      );
    }
    $add_submit = TRUE;
  }

  if ($add_submit) {
    // '#submit' is already set up due to the wizard.
    $form['#submit'][] = 'ctools_content_configure_form_defaults_submit';
  }
  return $form;
}
```

states on [line 513](https://cgit.drupalcode.org/ctools/tree/includes/content.inc#n513):

> // Unless we're not allowed to override the title on this content type, add this
>   // gadget to all panes.

which means you could just add the following array members to the existing $plugin or $subtype:

```
  $plugin['no title override'] = TRUE;
  $subtype['no title override'] = TRUE;
```

and theoretically it should work.